# Extract Month and Year from timestamp in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to extract month and year from Timestamp column(YYYYMMDD HHMMSS) and if month is 1,it should create a column called 'January' and month is 2,it should create column called 'February'.

Here is the query i have tried but no luck.

```
SELECT
  SUM(case when extract(month() from timestamp) = 1 and extract(year() from timestamp) = '2018' then total else 0 end ) as January ,
  SUM(case when extract(month() from timestamp) = 2 and extract(year() from timestamp) = '2018' then total else 0 end ) as February, and so on until December..

FROM x;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using Relational Database

Comment: which rdbms? mysql? sqlserver? oracle?

Comment: i am using oracle

Comment: So, why did you tag it with BigQuery if you're using Oracle?!

Comment: The term `didn't work` is too vague to be useful.

Comment: In bigquery,we use ORACLE like SQL..i have tagged only sql and bigquery

Comment: What do you mean you use _"ORACLE like SQL"_. I don't understand that. Are you using BigQuery or Oracle?

Comment: I am using Google Bigquery...

Answer (score 35):

Answering the title of the question as probably others will end up here like me looking for a way to create a YYYYMM year-month from a BigQuery timestamp.

This is the code I ended up with in standard SQL:

`CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR from timestamp) as string), LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from timestamp) as string),2,'0') )  as yearmonth`

Comment: how do i get these in two separate columns, two different extracts aren't working

Comment: So this does not work? Sadly I have no BigQuery to test it on currrently: 
`CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR from timestamp) as string) as year, LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from timestamp) as string),2,'0')  as month`

Answer (score 7):

I guess you're looking for this

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATETIME('%B', DATETIME '2008-12-25 15:30:00')
  AS formatted;
```

So `DATETIME` to cast your string to a datetime format and `format_datetime()` to get the name of the month

Comment: You said in the comments above that you're using Oracle.

Comment: In bigquery,we use oracle like SQL

Comment: that makes no sense

Answer (score 6):

Below is for BigQuery StandardSQL

```sql
#standardsQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION monthValue(ts TIMESTAMP, m INT64, y INT64, value INT64) AS (
  IF(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts) = m AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts) = y, value, 0) 
);
SELECT
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 1, 2018, total)) AS January,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 2, 2018, total)) AS February,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 3, 2018, total)) AS March,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 4, 2018, total)) AS April,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 5, 2018, total)) AS May,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 6, 2018, total)) AS June,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 7, 2018, total)) AS July,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 8, 2018, total)) AS August,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 9, 2018, total)) AS September,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 10, 2018, total)) AS October,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 11, 2018, total)) AS November,
  SUM(monthValue(timestamp, 12, 2018, total)) AS December
FROM
  `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

> Can we do this in Legacy SQL??

for Legacy SQL see below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 1 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS January,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 2 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS February,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 3 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS March,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 4 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS April,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 5 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS May,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 6 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS June,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 7 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS July,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 8 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS August,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 9 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS September,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 10 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS October,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 11 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS November,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(timestamp) = 12 AND YEAR(timestamp) = 2018, total, 0)) AS December
FROM [yourproject:yourdataset.yourtable]
```

Note: it is quite recommended by BigQuery Team to [`migrate to Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Comment: Can we do this in Legacy SQL??

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE (OrderDate)) AS STRING),"-",CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE (OrderDate)) AS STRING)) AS yyyy_mm
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your comment *"In bigquery, we use oracle like SQL"*, so I'm just going to assume you're using normal Standard SQL in BigQuery.

You're SQL is a little weird, and doesn't make a lot of sense, but here's a working example on a public dataset. You'll need to change the timestamp column to match yours, and I've no idea what `total` is, so I've just made it `1`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN EXTRACT(month  FROM  community_owned_date ) = 1 AND EXTRACT(year  FROM  community_owned_date ) = 2017 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END ) AS January,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN EXTRACT(month  FROM  community_owned_date ) = 2 AND EXTRACT(year  FROM  community_owned_date ) = 2017 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END ) AS February
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers`
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i run this query "Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 3, column 32. Was expecting: ")" ..."

Comment: You need to [enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql).