# Month and Year of from data_adm column in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the column data_adm I need to create a new "month_and_year" in bigquery how to do it?

SELECT data_adm,
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m', 'data_adm') AS year_and_month

FROM "table"

| data_adm | year_and_month |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-05 | 2022-12 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Month and Year from timestamp in Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206963/extract-month-and-year-from-timestamp-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 0):

You may try and consider below approach:

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select ('2022-12-05') as data_adm
)

select data_adm, FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', PARSE_DATE('%F', data_adm)) AS month_and_year from sample_data
```

**Sample output:**

[image]